# How does \newtheorem work?

Tags: theorems

I have a large .cls file I'm working with, so I don't know that I can provide a MSE, but here's my question. 
In my code I have:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
 \newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
 \newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}
 \newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
 \newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}
```

as well as:

```
\let\oldend\end
\renewcommand{\end}[1]{\IfEqCase{#1}{{}{\oldend{\@currenvir}}}[\oldend{#1}]}
```

I am using the xstring package for the `IfEqCase`, I'm not sure which package the theoremstyle is coming from. In any case, the goal was to create an `\end{}` that would simply end the current environment, if an input wasn't specified.

Interestingly, (to me at least), when I try to type: `\begin{proposition} \end{}` it gives me the error `! \LaTeX Error: \begin{proposition} on input line 6 ended by \end{proposition}`.

Given this information, does anyone know what's going on? I figure it must be someway that `\newtheorem` creates environments, but I also don't have any faith in my judgement.

Comment: `\theoremstyle` is defined by the `amsthm` package and selects one of the defined theorem styles.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to make use of that statement, mostly because I'm incompetent- What defined theorem styles? I'm also not sure what exactly a theorem style *is*.

Comment: `amsthm` defines the styles `plain`, `definition`, `remark`. You can define new styles on your own through the command `\newtheoremstyle`. See [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) for more info.

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212749/2417) help?

Comment: Yeah, that answer fixed it. Now I need to figure out why... Thanks Ian!

Comment: Definitely not a good idea.

Comment: The important part of the referenced answer in the duplicate question is **But you should not use it.**

Comment: I'm having issues seeing why- I realize that it isn't good structurally, at all. But I was trying to come up with a set of macros that would let me type my notes in class, and coming up with smaller commands lets me type my notes, even with my slower typing speed.

I mean I know it's bad fundamentally, but that's all right?