# Why do we need to specify which environment we end?

Tags: environments, syntax

Whenever we start an environment we have a `\begin{environment}`, and when we want to end an environment we write `\end{environment}` but shouldn't just `\end` be enough?

As far as I'm aware, the following is impossible:

```
\begin{coolstuff}
\begin{boringstuff}
\end{coolstuff}
\end{boringstuff}
```

And the following would be correct:

```
\begin{coolstuff}
\begin{boringstuff}
\end{boringstuff}
\end{coolstuff}
```

So why not just write:

```
\begin{coolstuff}
\begin{boringstuff}
\end
\end
```

??

Comment: With environments, the `\end` does more than just end the `\begin{<environment>}` by closing the group.  Environment-specific macros are executed as well, to assist in that close out.  Just look at the last argument provided in the definition of `\newenvironment`.

Comment: Also in HTML or XML you could use `</>`, couldn't you? Oh, well, this is not allowed, for the same reason it isn't in LaTeX.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205314/close-all-environments; duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212749/4427

Comment: thanks for the answers. The other questions didn't come up in my search XD